# Android Toolbar icons alignment issue

Tags: android, alignment, toolbar, gravity

I am using custom icons on toolbar in Android.

While my issue is i am not be able to align the 2 icons on the right side of the toolbar , that means aligning them at end.

Here is my actual toolbar image where these two icons are coming in center of the toolbar.

[image]

Attaching my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white">


  <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/innerToolbarLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvToolbarHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:text="Complaint Details"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/link_text_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold" />

     <ImageView

        android:tint="@color/link_text_color"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iviconSend"
        android:id="@+id/ivIconRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment_toolbar" />

     <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:tint="@color/link_text_color"
        android:id="@+id/iviconSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_email" />


      </RelativeLayout>


 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout1">

   <include
    android:id="@+id/composeMailtoolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_send_mail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:elevation="6dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**Note : I am including this layout in different main Layouts for toolbar.**

Please guide me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
android:gravity="center"
```

and make sure `android:layout_width="match_parent"` where ever you include this toolbar

below is working code for me

**layout_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvToolbarHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="Complaint Details"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/ivIconRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iviconSend"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iviconSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <CalendarView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I applied your modifications but still the same issue occuring, 
i have updated my main_activity.xml too on description above.
please check.

Comment: @javabee : If you have your code on git, Then i can try your code and fix it.Because i do not find any issue with above code.

Comment: The project is too huge to share on git, If u want i can share the related xmls fully.

Comment: @javabee : Can you create demo application(Single activity application) and upload it to git and just add your problem in demo application.I will check out and fix it.

Comment: need time for that one.  let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've aligned the attachment icon at the beginning of the send one:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvToolbarHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Complaint Details"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIconRight"
            android:tint="@color/link_text_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment_toolbar"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/iviconSend"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iviconSend"
            android:tint="@color/link_text_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_email"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

Comment: i have too attached the same in my code also. 
please do cross check.

Comment: Not the same, I've used "alignStartOf" in the first ImageView and the "center_verticals" are gone.